# How to enable portrait orientation for mobiles and portrait/landscape for tablets?

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt, qml

I'm currently working on a cross platform app (android and ios mostly). I would like to authorize the user to use landscape or portrait orientation when the screen is big enough (let's say over 480px width) and force him to use portrait in the other case.

I was thinking to use QML or C++ in order to achieve that, but apparently this is not possible. So I guess I will have to use AndroidManifest and Info.plist for iOS. But I don't see how I can define conditions in those files.

Any thought/help on how I could manage to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do with Qt. The trick is to include native code for each platform, as this is not supported by Qt out of the box. You can easily include both Android-Java and ios-objective-c code into your c++ app with a little work:

For Android, create a java class with the code from Pablo. Make use of the QtAndroid JNI wrappers to call those methods (See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroid.html and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#details).
**Pro Tip:** You can use https://github.com/benlau/androidnative.pri to call the java class. It's much easier than using the JNI classes, but requires a correct setup.

For ios, create a `mm` file, an object-c++ file, where you can mix c++ and objective-c code. Just create a c++ method, and in that method use object-c to archive your goal. It's most likly very similar to Pablos answer, but you cannot use swift.

Comment: Okay, first of all, thank you for all advices. I manage to use QtAndroid JNI wrappers to call java methods, but now I'm stuck. As I told Pablo, I don't understand how I should instanciate "activity" in his code. Am I supposed to pass this into parameter when I call the java method from C++ ?

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to make it work on Android, I'm gonna try on iOS now.

Comment: Even if you already have it, there are 2 "clean" ways. Either add the code to a custom class that extends `QtActivity` (directly in java), or get it from c++ using `QtAndroid::androidActivity`. There are other ways, but those to are the safe ones.

Answer (score -2):

Are you using hybrid or native apps?
Nevertheless you can change the screen orientation programmatically base on the display width.

First get the device display size and if the size is correct, change the orientation.

Here some code snippets.

**Swift 3.0**

```
//Get the display size
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height

//Change orientation
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

**Android**

```
//Get the display size
Point displaySize = new Point();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(displaySize);

Rect windowSize = new Rect();
activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(windowSize);

int width = displaySize.x - Math.abs(windowSize.width());
int height = displaySize.y - Math.abs(windowSize.height());

//Change orientation
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
//OR
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

If you are going with Cordova, you can use a plugin like this one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Comment: I'm using hybrid apps. Thanks for you code, but I don't understand where does the "activity" variable come from. Am I supposed to "get an instance" of the current activity ?

Comment: @highvoltage379 "activity" refers to the instance of the activity you are working on. Could be "this", "activity" or "context", the last two if you are receiving it by parameter. For instance if your are on a Fragment you can use `this.getActivity();`.